# Springboot: Micrometer @Timed base unit

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

does anybody known how to change the `@Timed` base unit from **seconds** to **milliseconds**.

I searched a lot, on the web and inside source code, but with no luck!

Thank you so much!

Comment: What meter registry are you using? Each registry defines its preferred time unit and that is how we publish time metrics. Just because something is shipped in seconds does not mean you cannot scale that as you want in a presentation layer (like Grafana). For example, if a value of 0.1 seconds is published to a metrics backend and you query it in Grafana, you can tell Grafana that it is seconds, and it may display 100 milliseconds instead. There's no need to change the base unit for this.